# How do I use the 95% confidence interval in r using the equation for a 95% confidence interval?

Tags: r, statistics, biometrics

How would I use the 95% Confidence Interval=(population mean) +/- 1.96 x(Standard error of the population mean) equation in program r to solve for the confidence interval? My bio-metrics professor wants us to use the equation but we can't figure out how to input it into Program R.

Comment: You want to calculate the CI of what? Please make your example reproducible by adding sample data (don't post screenshots, use `dput`).

Comment: It might be too late for your statistics professor, but there is a nice tutorial out there, that explains how to construct confidence intervals in R https://economictheoryblog.com/2019/01/11/confidence-intervals-in-r Furthermore, the tutorial also gives a very nice overview on the difference between confidence intervals using the normal distribution and confidence intervals using the t-distribution https://economictheoryblog.com/2019/03/07/what-is-the-difference-between-using-the-t-distribution-and-the-normal-distribution-when-constructing-confidence-intervals

Answer (score 3):

As you don't provide sample data, here is an example using the `iris` sample dataset. Specifically, let's calculate the 95% CI of the mean of the sepal widths.

1. Let's plot the distribution `Sepal.Width`

   ```
   library(ggplot)
   ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + geom_density()
   ```

[image]

2. The 95% confidence interval is defined by those observations that lie within 1.96 units of the standard deviation around the mean (assuming an underlying normal distribution).

   ```
   CI <- with(iris, mean(Sepal.Width) + c(-1, 1) * 1.96 * sd(Sepal.Width))
   CI
   #[1] 2.203035 3.911631
   ```
3. We confirm that indeed 95% of observations lie within `CI`

   ```
   with(iris, sum(Sepal.Width >= CI[1] & Sepal.Width <= CI[2]) / length(Sepal.Width))
   #[1] 0.9466667
   ```